# Shell Script executed twice

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a script which archives the files based on the list passed as an argument.Upon successful completion, an email is triggered with the status as completed. Below is my sample script

```
PROCESS_NAME="ArchivalProcess_001"
while IFS='' read -r line || [ "$line" ]
do
  # Archival process
done < "$1"
PROCESS_STATUS="Archival process has been success"
sh $MAIL_SH $PROCESS_NAME "$PROCESS_STATUS"
```

When I run the script MAIL_SH is executed twice and mail is triggered twice with same status. Can anybody help me with finding the error.

Comment: Are you sure the script is executed twice? One way to ensure would be to log to a file with timestamps and input params.

Comment: Unless you are doing something in `"# Archival process"` that causes one additional execution, the code you show above doesn't exhibit that  behavior. (stray characters on your final line of input may do it)

Comment: Does running the script under `set -x` provide a clue? Does the archival process call the script or mail anything?

Comment: Archival Process has the mail but with the different status. For me currently, the mail is triggered twice with the same status

Comment: @user8363477 : The error may equally well be in `$MAIL_SH`. I suggest that you pass as argument to it `"$PROCESS_STATUS $$"` to verify that the archival process really has been done twice.